# Uso da vírgula em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tendo um problema pra compreender qual a diferença entre o código 1 e o código 2 (sequência de Fibonacci). Aparentemente parecia a mesma coisa, mas os resultados que ambos imprimem são distintos.

## Código 1

```
qtd_elementos = int(input())
inicio = 1
somador = 0
lista_elementos = []

while (len(acumulador)) < qtd_elementos:
    somador, inicio = inicio, inicio + somador
    lista_elementos.append(somador)
print(acumulador)
```

## Código 2

```
qtd_elementos = int(input())
inicio = 1
somador = 0
lista_elementos = []

while (len(acumulador)) < qtd_elementos:
    somador = inicio
    inicio += somador
    lista_elementos.append(somador)
print(acumulador)
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vírgula aí separa duas expressões na linguagem. Em outros contextos pode ser uma interpretação um pouco diferente, mas sempre próximo a isso.

Neste caso do lado esquerdo do operador de atribuição está colocando duas variáveis `somador` e `inicio` e do lado direito está colocando as expressões `inicio` e `inicio + somador`. Em apenas uma linha consegue fazer duas atribuições distintas. Então é o mesmo que tivesse feito estas atribuições em linhas separadas, como foi feito no código 2. Portando é só um simplificador de sintaxe.

Porém há uma diferença importante no primeiro `somador` recebe o valor de `inicio` que ainda não foi alterado e só depois `inicio` recebe seu novo valor que é `inicio + somador` sendo que este `somador` usado agora ainda não recebeu o valor de `inicio`. É tudo como se fosse uma coisa só, é como se fosse assim:

```
tSomador = somador
somador = inicio
inicio += tSomador
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/MultiAssigmentDecomposed.py).

O segundo código não tem o armazenamento desta variável intermediária.

Isto é uma operação em tupla, embora alguns podem dizer que não já que a sintaxe de tupla é um pouco diferente.

E para finalizar, este código tem vários outros erros, tudo o que eu disse vale se os erros forem consertados.

Comment: Um exemplo que ilustra isso é que é possível trocar o valor de variáveis fazendo `a, b = b, a`.

Comment: Até porque este resultante de 3 linhas é o código de qualquer *swap*, fez fazer mágica :)